# How to aggregate data within non associative array in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, associative-array, aggregation-framework

I searched a lot before asking this question, but couldn't find any relevant information.

So here it is:

My problem is that I have a mongo collection in following format:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55bf4031eb8ac118a4b3110e"),
    "sid" : 1,
    "plugin_count" : [
      0,
      0,
      0,
      1,
      0,
      1,
      0,
      0,
      0, 
      0
    ],

},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55bf4031eb8ac118a4b3110e"),
    "sid" : 1,
    "plugin_count" : [
      2,
      1,
      0,
      6,
      0,
      10,
      12,
      0,
      16, 
      22
    ],

}
```

Now what I want to do is, I want to add all the elements present in non associative array individually and output them like this:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "_id": 1,
            "plugin_count": [
                2,
                1,
                0,
                7,
                0,
                11,
                12,
                0,
                16,
                22
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok": 1
}
```

My query is as follows

```
db.plugin_table.aggregate([
    {
        "$match" : {
            "sid" : {
                "$in" : [1]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind" : "$plugin_count"
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id": 1,
            "plugin_count" : {
                "$sum" : "$plugin_count"
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

But I am getting following output:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "_id": 1,
            "plugin_count": 0
        }
    ],
    "ok": 1
}
```

Please help I am literally pulling my hairs out. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really is no sane way to do this with the aggregation framework. The problem here is tracking the "index" position of the array elements, of which there is nothing that can do this.

Your best bet here is [mapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/command/mapReduce/), this can handle the problem quite simply, and scales well to any number of grouped keys:

```js
db.plugin_table.mapReduce(
    function () {
      emit(this.sid, { plugin_count: this.plugin_count });
    },
    function (key,values) {
      var result = { plugin_count: [] };

      values.forEach(function(value) {
        value.plugin_count.forEach(function(plugin,idx) {
          if ( result.plugin_count[idx] === undefined ) {
            result.plugin_count[idx] = plugin;
          } else {
            result.plugin_count[idx] += plugin;
          }
        });
      });

      return result;
    },
    { 
      "query": { "sid": 1 },
      "out": { "inline": 1 }
    }
)
```

This produces the required output, albiet in the form that mapReduce always produces output with the top level keys of `_id` and `value`:

```js
            {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "value" : {
                            "plugin_count" : [
                                    2,
                                    1,
                                    0,
                                    7,
                                    0,
                                    11,
                                    12,
                                    0,
                                    16,
                                    22
                            ]
                    }
            }
```

Note the reduce algorithm here also handles arrays of varying length with ease as everything is paired by index position or otherwise created if that position was not already present in the combined result per key.

---

The only *real* way the aggregation framework can handle this is to already have the data actually in a "associative array" instead, or at least have each element as an associative array in itself, like this:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55d32ffde12af47feb19bce7"),
    "sid" : 1,
    "plugin_count" : [
            {
                    "pos" : 0,
                    "value" : 0
            },
            {
                    "pos" : 1,
                    "value" : 0
            },
            {
                    "pos" : 2,
                    "value" : 0
            },
            {
                    "pos" : 3,
                    "value" : 1
            },
            {
                    "pos" : 4,
                    "value" : 0
            },
            {
                    "pos" : 5,
                    "value" : 1
            },
            {
                    "pos" : 6,
                    "value" : 0
            },
            {
                    "pos" : 7,
                    "value" : 0
            },
            {
                    "pos" : 8,
                    "value" : 0
            },
            {
                    "pos" : 9,
                    "value" : 0
            }
    ]
}
```

This is a basic transform along these lines:

```js
  db.junk.find().forEach(function(doc) { 
    doc.plugin_count = doc.plugin_count.map(function(value,idx) { 
      return { "pos": idx, "value": value };
    });
    db.newjunk.insert(doc);
  });
```

Then you have a basic aggregation, by simply grouping "first" on the "pos" elements and summing the results. The final array can be then formed by grouping back to "sid":

```js
  db.newjunk.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "sid": 1 } },
    { "$unwind": "$plugin_count" },
    { "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "sid": "$sid",
        "pos": "$plugin_count.pos"
      },
      "value": { "$sum": "$plugin_count.value" }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.sid",
      "plugin_count": { "$push": "$value" }
    }}
  ])
```

Which gives you the same output as earlier:

```js
{ "_id" : 1, "plugin_count" : [ 2, 1, 0, 7, 0, 11, 12, 0, 16, 22 ] }
```

Also noting here that you could avoid the [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) stage here by keeping the associative information. Using [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) will not guarantee the positions stay the same, but with the associative information this is not really required.

So it all comes down to what you can live with. If you want to keep the plain array in data then you are going to need mapReduce to get the result. If however you are willing to change the data format, then the aggregate method is totally possible.

However this might just well be a good case where at "large scale" the mapReduce process would beat the aggregation process by avoiding the overhead of processing [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Blakes. Actually we did not use the indexes to save space as this collection consists of 1 million+ records. But will surely use the mapReduce part. One quick question though, will using mapReduce have any impact on performance?

Comment: @LankeshZade I am talking about "array indexes" meaning the "position in the array", and not "database indexes" as you have mistaken the term for. As for performance, mapReduce uses JavaScript  for it's command execution. So yes there is a cost over a lot of aggregation framework operations due to that evaluation and "thunking" of BSON types to JavaScipt types. However, as I do state already in the answer, whilst aggregate uses native operators, the "cost" of processing `$unwind` here is likely greater than the performance hit from mapReduce. Benchmark the two forms where possible.

Comment: Will keep that in mind.Thank you for your time @Blakes. Sorry for the late reply.